# Ethereum Address Validation

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, ico

Currently, i am using web.utils.isAddress function to check whether ETH Address is valid or not. Is it right?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! If you're using web3 version 1.x then `web3.utils.isAddress` is the right way.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#isaddress

If you're on older versions (0.2x.x) of web3 then `web3.isAddress` is the correct way to determine if a given hex string is a valid Ethereum address.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3isaddress